# Objective-C EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: random, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

Ok so I've recently decided to try to teach myself Objective-C (I'm interested in iPhone development), however I've never used C or any of its derivatives before, and as such am running into some problems.
I decided to start out by writing a very basic card application that creates a deck of cards, shuffles the deck, and then displays the cards on the screen using UIButtons, however I'm having a problem with my shuffling algorithm. Every time it gets called I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, which I know means there's something desperately wrong with my code, but I just can't figure out what it is.

```
- (void) randomize {
    NSMutableArray *tmpDeck = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(Card *tmp in _cards) {
        BOOL didInsert = NO;
        while(!didInsert) {
            NSUInteger random = arc4random_uniform(54);
            if([[tmpDeck objectAtIndex:random] isEqual:nil]) {
                [tmpDeck insertObject:tmp atIndex:random];
                didInsert = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    _cards = tmpDeck;
    _hasBeenRandomized = YES;
}
```

_cards is a pointer to an NSMutableArray containing the unshuffled deck of card objects, and _hasBeenRandomized is a boolean (obviously) that keeps track of whether or not the deck has been randomized.

I've tried to use the debugger to work out what exactly is going on here, but I can't even step into the method without my program crashing. This leads me to believe that the problem has to come from the very first line, but it's just a straightforward creation of an NSMutableArray, so I don't know how it could be that. This method is being called from within viewDidLoad. This is the entirety of the viewDidLoad method currently.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _deck = [[Deck alloc] init];
    [_deck randomize];
}
```

Any and all help will be appreciated. Sorry if the answer is dead obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to insert into an index that doesn't exist yet. You need to initialize the array with as many places in the array as you need for your cards. Either that or use a NSMutableDictionary and just insert the object with the index being the key.

To add another note, calling initWithCapacity on the array wouldn't solve this for you either since this just gives a "hint" at the size. You need the count property of the array to actually be at least as large as the index you are trying to insert. If you wanted to do an array, then you would first need to populate something in each index first. You could define this in the new array literal format or use a for loop that loops the number of times you need (your max index) and insert a dummy object in it's place.

```
for (int i=0; i< _cards.count; ++i) 
{
    [tmpDeck insertObject:@"dummy" atIndex:i];
}
```

Then instead of checking for 'nil' before you replace, you check if it is equal to the dummy object you inserted. This would give you an array that you can insert into any of these indexes. I personally would still probably store them in an NSMutableDictionary. But if you need it in an array for some other purpose then this is a way to do it.

You also will need to be sure to replace the object instead of inserting, otherwise you will just keep adding indexes.

```
[tmpDeck replaceObjectAtIndex:random withObject:tmp];
```

If you still get the same error, set a breakpoint in your debugger and check what the random number is and what the count of your array is. If your random number is ever greater than your array count, then you will get this error.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by this. I know that you have to initialize the size of arrays in languages like Java, but I created the original NSMutableArray holding the cards in order without specifying the number of indices I would need. From that I assumed that you just didn't need to specify the size of arrays in Objective-C. Any idea why it worked in the first case but not in this one? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the cards in the original array were inserted in order, versus at random indexes? The first array is created during the initialization of the Deck object. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can specify the size of the array. But this is just a hint to the compiler on how much "memory" you need and doesn't mean the mutable array won't expand. If you init the array with objects, or push them sequentially, then the array will keep adding one more index. However, you can't just access an index that hasn't been created yet. I'll write what I would personally do in this situation in an edit for you. Note that you can also add multiple objects at a time to an NSMutableArray and even declare them now using a literal.

Comment: Scratch that, the way I was going to do it required an extra iteration of the whole array, so then we have to weigh the two evils which I won't do now. Anyway, I hope this helps, a great resource for this stuff is Apple's developer documentation. Read up a little about NSMutable Array/Dictionary's.

Comment: By the way, if you go the NSDictionary route, you will need to convert the index to an object for the key. You can do a number literal like this @(random).

Comment: Johnrechd, thanks very much for the help, but unfortunately I still get the same EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I used your code exactly. It runs a for loop, which fills the array with @"dummy"'s, and then, instead of checking for nil, it checks for @"dummy". Unfortunately I still get an error at runtime.

Comment: I'll try the dictionary and see how things go.

Comment: I edited my comment to be more thorough. You need to do a replace instead of an insert since you are replacing the object at the index.

Comment: Ok, so after looking more into things, I think that there must be something wrong with my init method for the Deck object, because it doesn't matter what's inside of the randomize method, it always crashes. The program appears to crash any time I try to run methods on my deck object. This would also explain why I can't step inside the method with the debugger. So, thank you very much for the help, and I'm sure that once I get the init method working, all of what you have said will be very helpful.